# Convert form with form arrays into a vaild json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

My form looks like this.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="pic" value="test" />
    <input type="text" name="person[0].name" value="Bob" />
    <input type="text" name="person[0].age" value="25" />
    <input type="text" name="person[1].name" value="Jim"/>
    <input type="text" name="person[1].age" value="30" />
</form>
```

Is their a method that can take in any form and if the name of several form elements is the same then make them into an array under the initial name in json.

The json object would ideally look like

```
    {
      "pic" : "test",
      "person":[
                {"name":"Bob", "age":"25"}, 
                {"name":"Jim", "age":"30"}
               ]
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that I think I can modify that to serve my purpose.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/8407771#8407771 for assistance. one of the repos cited in the answer https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object/blob/master/jquery.serialize-object.js is not quite going to quite work with the '.' (dot) syntax in your binding, but it comes pretty close. if you can use '[' bracket syntax the repo might just work.

Comment: Have you tried person[0][name] instead of person[0].name in your html form?

Comment: The .name is how the framework binds it to the model

Answer (score 0):

I found a library that handles this

[form2js](https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js)